# Как передавать пароль ssh автоматически из Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd, cygwin

Подскажите, как можно передавать пароль для создания ssh туннеля из под Windows автоматически чтобы он не спрашивал. Почитал man там только о Linux
P.S. использую cygwin, использование putty не желательно

Для подключения использую такую команду:

```
ssh -R 22:localhost:5551 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no login@IP "ls -la"
```

Comment: Никола, судя по последним пяти вашим вопросам имеет смысл кратко рассказать о задаче в целом. Обычно мы рекомендуем максимально сузить вопрос, однако (лично мне) кажется, что в данном случае будет уместно пояснить общую задачу. Возможно, так вы быстрее придёте к магистральному направлению, куда вести решение. Подпишите в конец задания. Вы хотите создавать ssh туннели автоматически, это понятно. Но зачем?

Comment: А зачем вообще создаются тоннели для шифровки трафика

Comment: Тоннели для шифровки трафика создаются руками, разово. А вот зачем тоннели создавать массово, автоматизированным способом -- для меня загадка. Подозреваю, что это нужно спамерам, ботнетчикам и вообще не есть хорошая практика. А теперь скажите вы, зачем вы создаёте тоннели для шифровки трафика? )

Answer (score 2):

Принято не передавать пароли автоматически.
В SSH для этого используются SSH ключи. Генерите пару ключей, публичный ключ настраивается на удаленном хостинге, приватный остается у вас, и подключаетесь по ssh без запроса пароля.

ssh-keygen - сгенерирует пару ключей
ssh-copy-id user@host - скопирует публичный ключ на удаленный сервер (нужно будет ввести пароль)
после этого все ssh команды будут работать без запроса пароля.